# On the fly file encryption in Windows server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, encryption, backup, gnupg

Is there a possibility to encrypt a file "on the fly" in windows while copying file via FTP to remote storage?

i don't know if that description is good enough but i want to do something in the way of `gpg -e file > ftp://xxx`

or will i just have to rely on cygwin?

i'm using windows server 2008 R2 and the file i'm copying is around 750GB in size so it's not possible to encrypt it first and then copy it.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question.  Perhaps Server Fault would be a better fit?

Answer (score 0):

The file as written to local storage via ftp will simply reflect the bytes sent to it from the client. It would have to be encrypted after it was received,b as ftp has no native encryption that I know of.

Comment: the file is allready stored on my server, i am just wondering if windows offers the capability to redirect the output stream of gpg to an ftp share

Answer (score 0):

Not with anything built in to  FTP. If you used SFTP or SCP, or WEBDEV over SSL/TLS, you could get encryption for trassport, but the data on the other end will still be encrypted. In fact, the lack of encryption ( for transport) in FTP was why SFTP was developed

If you don't mind writing some code, you cause C# to encrypt data as its copying it over very easily.

Get a crypto-stream from AES and simply back the stream with a network stream/ftp stream . This should avoid writing the data back to disk. You'd simply be reading of disk a few bytes at a time, encrypting, and then writing the data to the network.

You might be able to do a similar thing with powershell.

Comment: Ah, missunderstood your question. No that won't work. I've updated the answer to reflect your actual question